# Can I book tickets on Easyjet with a V Pay card?

Tags: bookings, payment-cards, easyjet

I have a V PAY card from Sparkasse (German Bank), can i use it to book tickets at easyjet?
Because there is no option for V PAY but for all other types of VISA.

Comment: V-Pay is not a credit card. It's a debit card (ec-karte)

Comment: Yes i know it's debit card,but i have VISA debit card also of another country (not V PAY) and i can by that. Otherwise easyjet accepts debit cards. My question is especially for V PAY.

Comment: http://www.easyjet.com/de/zahlung-elektronischen-lastschriftverfahren-de you can pay by direct withdrawal if book the flight at least 2 weeks ahead

Comment: I have seen that too, i don't actually can do that. I just only wanted to learn if i can do that by V PAY. Anyway, very thanks for your responses.

Comment: As v-pay is a debit card, AFAIK that's the only way to pay with it.

Comment: But they accept debit cards for sure,maybe not v pay.

Comment: You can pay with your V Card its working :)) When you have to pay, just click on the grey square where written Zahlung im Lastschriftverfahren
It took me a while to find out as well !!
Have a good trip !

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can pay with a German bank account. From [easyjet.com](http://www.easyjet.com/book/paymentoptions):

> German residents with a German bank account booking on the German
>   website will be offered ELV as a payment option. The ELV payment
>   option will only be offered for transactions in Euros, and only if the
>   flight is more than 14 days away from the date of booking. There is a
>   14 day clearing period on ELV payments, which means that flight
>   changes cannot be made until 14 days after the date your last payment
>   was made. Please note that ELV payments that are rejected by the
>   issuing bank will incur an additional fee when resubmitted for
>   payment. For the purposes of any refunds payable by easyJet in
>   accordance with our Carrier’s Regulations or Conditions of Carriage,
>   you agree that such refund may be made by cheque in Euros for the
>   applicable amount.

Comment: Actually i answered that above but again,I have seen that too. I just only wanted to learn if i can do that by V PAY not bank account. Anyway, very thanks for your responses.